# How to move between Datagridview Cells by Enter key in edit mode C#

Tags: c#, datagridview

The code I will attach it works for me to add new row only if all cells not empty but when I tried to edit any pervious row contain data it takes me to next row and next column

> **Example**

if I click on rowIndex = 0 , ColumnIndex = 1 and I press Enter it takes me to rowIndex = 1 , ColumnIndex = 2
.

```
    private void grid1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        int iColumn = grid1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;

        int iRow = grid1.CurrentCell.RowIndex;

        if (iColumn == grid1.Columns.Count - 2)
        {

            foreach (DataGridViewRow rw in this.grid1.Rows)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < rw.Cells.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (rw.Cells[i].Value == null || rw.Cells[i].Value == DBNull.Value || String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(rw.Cells[i].Value.ToString()))
                    {
                        flag2 = true;
                    }
                    else
                        flag2 = false;
                }
            }

            if (flag2)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Fill the Blanks");
            }
            else
            {
                grid1.Rows.Add();
                grid1.CurrentCell = grid1[0, iRow + 1];
            }
        }
        else
        {
            DataGridViewCell cell = grid1[iColumn + 1, iRow];
            NextCell(iColumn, iRow);

        }
    }
```

.

```
    protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
    public void NextCell(int col, int row)
    {
        int count = grid1.ColumnCount;

        int colindex = col + 1;
        try { 
        if (colindex < count)
        {
            DataGridViewCell cell = grid1[colindex, row];

            if (cell.Visible == true)
            {
                grid1.CurrentCell = cell;
            }
            else
            {
                NextCell(colindex, row);
            }
        }
        }
        catch {  }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank You all I solve it by me self.

```
private void grid1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
                // I left it empty
      }
```

..

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
        {
            bool insiderFlage = false;
            bool flag2 = true;

            int icolumn = grid1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;
            int irow = grid1.CurrentCell.RowIndex;

            if (keyData == Keys.Enter)
            {
                if (icolumn == grid1.Columns.Count - 2)
                {
                    foreach (DataGridViewRow rw in this.grid1.Rows)
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < rw.Cells.Count; i++)
                        {
                            if (rw.Cells[i].Value == null || rw.Cells[i].Value == DBNull.Value || String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(rw.Cells[i].Value.ToString()))
                            {
                                flag2 = true;                                 
                            }
                            else
                                flag2 = false;
                        }
                    }
                    if (flag2)
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < grid1.ColumnCount; i++)
                        {
                            if (grid1.CurrentRow.Cells[i].Value == null || grid1.CurrentRow.Cells[i].Value == DBNull.Value || String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(grid1.CurrentRow.Cells[i].Value.ToString()))
                            {

                                insiderFlage = true;
                            }
                        }
                        if (insiderFlage) MessageBox.Show("Fill All Blanks", "!");
                        else
                            grid1.CurrentCell = grid1[0, irow + 1];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        grid1.Rows.Add();
                        grid1.CurrentCell = grid1[0, irow + 1];
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    grid1.CurrentCell = grid1[icolumn + 1, irow];
                }
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
            }
         }
```